# Angular and Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I was following a tutorial on [implementation of angular and rails](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/2013/12/11/beginners-guide-to-angular-js-rails) and I ran into problems performing data binding. I followed the tutorial perfectly but I hit a stumbling block I cannot solve. I am trying to display the value of foo in public/templates/home.html.

Here is my code:

**public/templates/home.html**

```
 Value of "foo": {{ foo }}
```

**app/assets/angular/controllers/HomeCtrl.js.coffee**

```
 @restauranteur.controller 'HomeCtrl', ['$scope', ($scope) ->
     $scope.foo = 'bar'
   ]
```

**app/assets/javascripts/main.js.coffee**

```
@restauranteur = angular.module('restauranteur', [])
@restauranteur.config(['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) ->
  $routeProvider.
    otherwise({
      templateUrl: '../templates/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    }) 
])
```

**app/assets/javascripts/angular/controllers/HomeCtrl.js.coffee**

```
@restauranteur.controller 'HomeCtrl', ['$scope', ($scope) ->
]
```

Comment: why do you have two controllers with the same name?

Comment: I just noticed that and am resolving it now. Thanks

Comment: I think this tutorial is incorrect. It tells the reader to create 2 directories with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

The [tutorial](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/2013/12/11/beginners-guide-to-angular-js-rails) I was following incorrectly told me to create 2 controllers with the same name. Once I deleted the controller *app/assets/angular/controllers/HomeCtrl.js.coffee* I was good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Check and see if `main.js.cofee` file is included, in your chrome console under sources tab. I also had the same issue. This issue comes when you do `//=require ./angular` or something like that. If you want the file to get included, then just paste it under `app/assets/angular` directory and after that you might have to shift your angular directory inside `app/assets/javascript` directory.